# Can the Area of a Shape be determined from its Perimeter, and the Perimeter of a Line of Fixed Normal Distance from the First?

Tags: geometry, area

If I have a shape, and I draw a border around it where the distance between my border and the shape is constant, is it possible to calculate the area of the shape by measuring the perimeter lengths of the original shape and my border?

For instance, if I had two rollers for measuring distance rigged together at a fixed distance from each other of one foot, and I measured a shape on the ground, would those two different perimeter measurements let me find the area?

If I could determine the average curvature from the two perimeters, then I suspect that the circle with that same curvature would have an area the same as the original shape, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You cannot. Let's say you have a convex oval like shape with smooth boundary and perimeter $L$. If you draw a [parallel curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_curve) on its outside at a fixed normal distance $\rho$, the perimeter on the new curve will be $L + 2\pi \rho$. The pair of distances need not carry any information about the area.